# Most non-hacky way to make a modal window popup when unauthorized to navigate to a page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My goal is to make a modal window popup if a user clicks on a link to a page (or POSTs a form) for which he is unauthorized, as it is a better user experience than redirecting to a generic error page.

What I did is implement

```
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // ... 
    }
```

so that if the request is a non-AJAX request then it redirects to the same page (gives the illusion of staying on the same page) and appends the query string with `"forbiddenRedirect=true"` and then JavaScript opens the error modal. I'm trying to think of a better way than using the query string. From what I can tell, there's no way for JavaScript to access response headers, only the URL. That's why I went with the query string solution. But maybe in MVC there's some way I can redirect and pass some sort of token that the base controller can recognize and then add something to the view bag like `ViewBag.IsRedirectFromUnauthorizedAction = true`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**The user should never get to a page where they can post data without being authenticated and authorised!**

If your users can get to forms where they can post information (lets go with a User Profile Page), they should be authenticated before they can even get there. So for example, you would lead the user to a *Log in* page **before** you allow them to access the *Edit Profile* page. Once they have authenticated themselves and you have checked they are authorised to perform a POST on a particular page, **then** you present them with the form.

**But what if their session times out?**

In the event that the user authenticates and gets to that page, then their session times out, you should redirect them back to the *Log in* page where they are prompted for their credentials again and deny their post request. In an ideal scenario, you should have an AJAX function running in the background every 30 seconds or so. If they are idle for a set period of time (lets say 5 minutes) then you can assume they have closed the browser or left their PC unattended. At this point, either ask the user (via modal window) if they'd like to stay logged in or be logged out in 30 seconds. If they click the *Stay logged in* button, leave them be. If they don't answer, you can log them out and automatically redirect them back to the Login page.